Использование MongoDB в России
Будут ли обрабатываться запросы из России, которые отправляются с React приложения на базу данных MongoDB ?

"Официальная" бесплатная и платная Монга для РФ закрыта. Все данные на ней были удалены. О чем ранее владельцы предупреждали. Организовывай свой сервер или работай с теми, кто такие возможности дает.

@ksa, понял, спасибо. Есть варианты, с кем можно поработать ?

У нас свой сервер...

@ksa, хорошо, спасибо
